# bootsrap nav not responding well when layout changes

Tags: asp.net, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-brand pull-left">
                <a href="#" class="pull-left">
                    <img width="150" height="45" class="navbar-left" src="Intellicell_files/IntelliCell-Logo.png" /></a>
            </div>
            <button class="navbar-toggle pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse pull-right">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-text">
                    <li><a id="homeLink" href="#" data-target="home_container">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a id="contractslink" href="Contracts.aspx">Contracts</a></li>
                    <li><a id="accounts" href="AccountHistory.aspx">Account History</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="modal">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a id="refer" href="#">Refer a Friend</a></li>
                    <li><a id="tracker" href="#">Incentive Tracker</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="center-block" id="divider">
            <div class="nav-divider">
                <h4 class="text-center">HOME</h4>
                <%--<asp:Button Text="Logout" CssClass="btn btn-group-sm form-control" ID="btnLogOut" runat="server" align="right" OnClick="btnLogOut_Click"/>--%>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

the problem comes when I test the Navbar on a tablet and that causes the navbar to go under the logo that i have put there, so i was wondering if there is a way of making sure that the nav logo and the nav options are always on the same line. i am using bootstrap by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to reduce the padding between your links.

Also, see the Docs regarding how to structure a default [navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar).

```css
.navbar .navbar-brand {
  padding-top: 3px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img width="150" height="45" src="http://placehold.it/150x45/f00" />
      </a>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a id="homeLink" href="#" data-target="home_container">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li><a id="contractslink" href="Contracts.aspx">Contracts</a>

        </li>
        <li><a id="accounts" href="AccountHistory.aspx">Account History</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="modal">Contact Us</a>

        </li>
        <li><a id="refer" href="#">Refer a Friend</a>

        </li>
        <li><a id="tracker" href="#">Incentive Tracker</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">

            <button class="navbar-toggle pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <div class="navbar-brand">
                <a href="#">
                    <img height="45" class="navbar-left" src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/PDfWeUP09TA/hqdefault.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-text">
                    <li><a id="homeLink" href="#" data-target="home_container">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a id="contractslink" href="Contracts.aspx">Contracts</a></li>
                    <li><a id="accounts" href="AccountHistory.aspx">Account History</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="modal">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a id="refer" href="#">Refer a Friend</a></li>
                    <li><a id="tracker" href="#">Incentive Tracker</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="center-block" id="divider">
            <div class="nav-divider">
                <h4 class="text-center">HOME</h4>
                <%--<asp:Button Text="Logout" CssClass="btn btn-group-sm form-control" ID="btnLogOut" runat="server" align="right" OnClick="btnLogOut_Click"/>--%>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


ul li a{
    padding-left: 10px !important;
    padding-right: 10px !important;
}
```

Im not frontend, but it should help :)

I wrapped img and ul by div, and thru smaller padding get img to row with menu.
Its just a suggest, problem is, `ul li a` is too big, and push img up